# Is a sort of foreach statement possible in t-sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreach

I have data like this and I am trying to make a table based on t-sql that allows me to see for each unique CPR if the table has a line with both paymenttype 23 and 26, which is the case with CPR 123 below.

It should be fairly simple, but I am new to t-sql and haven't found solutions. Years back with SAS I vaguely recall using a "foreach" statement for stuff like this.

Any help would be very appreciated.

| CPR | Paymenttype |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 23 |
| 123 | 26 |
| 111 | 28 |
| 144 | 26 |
| 144 | 27 |

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you update the tags and add the lagnuage of interest here?

Comment: Firstly, I think both Oracle and Microsoft have languages which are referred to as "T-SQL", so you'll need to specify which. Secondly, while there _are_ ways of writing loops in such languages, it's generally a poor approach to the problem; it's nearly always better to try to think in terms of set-wise operations, and write an SQL query. From the limited information you give, it sounds like `WHERE EXISTS (...) AND EXISTS (...)` would do the job here, although there are more efficient ways if you have a lot of data.

Comment: Thank you @IMSoP, it is Microsoft. If set-wise operation is better, that is absolutely fine.

Comment: Thank you @kvantour, tags now corrected

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do this in more-or-less portable SQL. It's a job for GROUP BY ... HAVING.

```sql
SELECT CPR
  FROM tbl
 WHERE PaymentType IN (23,26)
 GROUP BY CPR
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

If you were looking for items with any combination of three out of five PaymentTypes, you could do this.

```sql
SELECT CPR
  FROM tbl
 WHERE PaymentType IN (23, 26, 28, 50, 31)
 GROUP BY CPR
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3;
```

The trick here is to remember SQL is a *declarative* language, not a *procedural* language.  You describe the set of results you need, and SQL figures out how to get it for you.  `foreach` is a procedural sort of operation.

Comment: For the first query, I would rather say `having count(distinct PaymentType) = 2` - we know nothing about possible duplicates.Although the execution plan will probably become considerably less palatable.

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding whether T-SQL supports ForEach**

While there is no `ForEach`, there are similar constructs (like `WHILE` loop and `CURSOR` etc.) that can be used to simulate a `ForEach` loop. However, I would advise you not to use them, unless you are out of options.

**Regarding solution to your problem**

There are many ways. Here is one easy way to do it using co-related query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CPR
FROM YourTable T
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE CPR = T.CPR AND Paymenttype = 23)
  AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE CPR = T.CPR AND Paymenttype = 26)
```

Comment: Or, more simply: `... where T.PaymentType = 23 and exists ( select 42 from YourTable as YT26 where YT26.CPR = T.CPR and YT26.PaymentType = 26 );`. There is no need to use `exists` for every value when you can simply filter on one of them. Aside: Best practice is to use a table alias on _every_ reference where there can be any confusion.

Comment: @HABO, yes you are right. But that makes things more complicated to comprehend for people like OP who are just beginning to understand the concepts.